# Java import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job; does not sleep

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I am about to implement a debugger for Eclipse. For this I want to use a `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job;` Objetct to handle the event when my debugging device reaches a breakpoint. In this case `thread.resume()` returns. Even though the thread is suspended, `Job` does not sleep:

```
Output:
program suspended
cannot sleep
<repeat to infinity>
```

This is the code:

```
@Override
protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {

  while (isTerminated() == false) {

    try {
      if (thread.isSuspended() == true) {
        System.out.println("program suspended");
        if(sleep() == true) { // wait for someone to wake me up
          System.out.println("job is sleeping");                            
        } else {
          System.out.println("cannot sleep");
        }            
      } else {
        thread.resume();
      }
    } catch (DebugException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 

  }
  return Status.OK_STATUS;      
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Job.sleep() always does nothing and returns false when the job is running, it is intended for use when the job is still scheduled to run. Just use an ordinary thread for your code.

Comment: Yeah, came to the same solution and replaced it by a thread. Thanks